# Using appropriate data types (path, string, etc.) with boost::filesystem in C++ to efficiently iterate files, change filenames, and do file operations

Tags: c++, boost

The following code loops through files in "sourcepath" and copies them to "destpath".  If they exist, they are renamed as "Copy of" the original filename.

Do I really need this much code for this?  I get the feeling I'm doing way too much back-and-forth converting between strings and paths, but I'm not sure how else to do it.

Is there a less complicated and more efficient way to do this, or is this as good as it gets?

System: Win32(XP), Boost libraries: 1.44 v2, Dev env: Visual Studio TS 2008

```
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

bfs::path pathSource("C:/dir/sourcepath");
bfs::path pathDest("C:/dir/destpath");

for (bfs::directory_iterator iterDir(pathSource); 
    iterDir!=bfs::directory_iterator(); iterDir++)
{
    std::string strSourceFilename(pathSource.string() + "/" 
        + iterDir->filename());
    std::string strDestFilename(pathDest.string() + "/" 
        + iterDir->filename());
    bfs::path pathSourceFilename(strSourceFilename);
    bfs::path pathDestFilename(strDestFilename);

    if(!bfs::exists(pathDestFilename))
        bfs::copy_file(pathSourceFilename, pathDestFilename);
    else {
        std::string strNewDestFilename(pathDest.string() 
            + "/" + "Copy of " + iterDir->filename());
        bfs::path pathNewDestFilename(strNewDestFilename);
        bfs::copy_file(pathSourceFilename, pathNewDestFilename);
    }
}
```

**ETA: Moved "Copy of" to the right place (next to the filename rather than the dir name).**

**ETA2: Refactored using suggested edits:**

```
namespace bfs = boost::filesystem;

bfs::path pathSource("C:/dir/sourcepath");
bfs::path pathDest("C:/dir/destpath");

for (bfs::directory_iterator iterDir(pathSource); 
    iterDir!=bfs::directory_iterator(); iterDir++)
{
    bfs::path pathSourceFilename(pathSource / iterDir->filename());
    bfs::path pathDestFilename(pathDest / iterDir->filename());

    if(!bfs::exists(pathDestFilename))
        bfs::copy_file(pathSourceFilename, pathDestFilename);
    else {
        std::string strNewDestFilename("Copy of " + iterDir->filename());
        bfs::path pathNewDestFilename(pathDest / strNewDestFilename);
        bfs::copy_file(pathSourceFilename, pathNewDestFilename);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`path` objects have overloaded `/` operator, which appends the second operand with a separator to the path.

Your

```
std::string strSourceFilename(pathSource.string() + "/" 
    + iterDir->filename());
std::string strDestFilename(pathDest.string() + "/" 
    + iterDir->filename());
bfs::path pathSourceFilename(strSourceFilename);
bfs::path pathDestFilename(strDestFilename);
```

can be written as

```
bfs::path pathSourceFilename(pathSource / iterDir->filename());
bfs::path pathDestFilename(pathDest / iterDir->filename());
```

(Same with `pathNewDestFilename`).

Comment: I edited above, using a string for the new filename and the / operator to assemble the path.  Thanks! :)